# Javascript created SVG shows in inspector but not on screen

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Here is the test code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>

  </style>
  <title>xyz</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <svg id="mysvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="360" height="360">
    <line x1="1" y1="1" x2="359" y2="359" stroke="black"/>
    <circle cx="100.00" cy="100.00" r="25.17" fill="#00ffff"
        stroke="red"/>
      </svg>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
  // used all over
  const svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
  let svg_el = document.getElementById("mysvg");
  let sh_el = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
  sh_el.setAttributeNS(svgNS, "x", "150");
  sh_el.setAttributeNS(svgNS, "y", "150");
  sh_el.setAttributeNS(svgNS, "stroke", "blue");
  sh_el.setAttributeNS(svgNS, "width", "10");
  sh_el.setAttributeNS(svgNS, "height", "40");
  svg_el.appendChild(sh_el);
</script>

</html>
```

In Firefox using the inspector I see the line, circle and rect elements but the rect does not display. I've looked at other Stackoverflow answers and I don't think it's a name-space issue. My best guess is that the DOM is not updated but I don't know how that could happen

Comment: Try using setAttribute instead of setAttributeNS

Answer (score 1):

As James suggests in the comments, the attributes should not be in a namespace. You can see in your static SVG markup that the attributes are not in a namespace (they don't have a prefix). Using `setAttribute` instead of `setAttributeNS` fixes the issue.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>

  </style>
  <title>xyz</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <svg id="mysvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="360" height="360">
    <line x1="1" y1="1" x2="359" y2="359" stroke="black"/>
    <circle cx="100.00" cy="100.00" r="25.17" fill="#00ffff"
        stroke="red"/>
      </svg>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
  // used all over
  const svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
  let svg_el = document.getElementById("mysvg");
  let sh_el = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
  sh_el.setAttribute("x", "150");
  sh_el.setAttribute("y", "150");
  sh_el.setAttribute("stroke", "blue");
  sh_el.setAttribute("width", "10");
  sh_el.setAttribute("height", "40");
  svg_el.appendChild(sh_el);
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, that absolutely works. Thank you. I used the NS version of SetAttribute because of what I saw on the MDN SVG documentation [Namespaces crash course](https://developerthe NS .mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course). It says that NS versions should be used for DOM 2 and that implied to me it would be the way to go for SVG, which uses a name-space.

Comment: @MWade It is very common to have an XML schema where the elements are in a namespace, but the attributes are not in a namespace, and SVG is one of those cases. So you should use the NS methods when creating SVG elements, but the non-NS versions when dealing with their attributes.